# Undefined symbols for architecture when instantiating a class

Tags: c++

I am getting an error when I try to instantiate my class in my main function.  I am new to C++ so this is likely an understanding issue, any help would be appreciated though.

This is the error:

Ld /Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Products/Debug/Bayesian\ Backend normal x86_64 (in target 'Bayesian Backend' from project 'Bayesian Backend')
    cd /Users/eitangerson/Desktop/Finance/Bayesian\ Backend
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Debug/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bayesian\ Backend.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Debug/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bayesian\ Backend_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -lboost_system -ljsoncpp -lcurlpp -lcurl -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Debug/Bayesian\ Backend.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bayesian\ Backend_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/eitangerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bayesian_Backend-brxcabimwmnocqehnjlnryhdizzb/Build/Products/Debug/Bayesian\ Backend

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Datapull::Datapull(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
class Datapull{
    string amount = "All";

public:

    Datapull(string name);
    string name = name;
    string path = "/Users/eitangerson/desktop/Finance/"+ name +".json";


public:

    void wrapper(){
        if(exists_test("/Users/eitangerson/desktop/Finance/" + name + ".csv") != 0){
            amount = "some";
        }
        pullData();
    }
```

...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<string> names{"ENPH","SILV","TSLA"};
    for(string &ii : names){
        Datapull DP(ii);
        DP.wrapper();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clang+symbol%28s%29+not+found+for+architecture+x86_64

Comment: Hi. I went through the other examples, and I still do not understand.